# source path/to/script hangs after a faiure

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run an android rom build. I start the build with:

`source build/envsetup.sh`

This normally only takes a moment to execute; however, after running it the first time, and starting the build, my system crashed. Now when I execute that command, it takes about 30 minutes for it to complete.
I have completely deleted rom source and pulled it again. I cleared cache, delete .bash_history log, delete the out dir in the build tree, and rebooted. Others are not having any issues with launching a build for this rom. Any ideas how to fix this?

[build/envsetup.sh][1]: https://github.com/Evolution-X/build/blob/udc/envsetup.sh

And there is no error. It just hangs with

```
including vendor/evolution/vendorsetup.sh
```

[vendor/evolution/vendorsetup.sh](https://github.com/Evolution-X/vendor_evolution/blob/udc/vendorsetup.sh)

[using set -x](https://hastebin.com/share/luseboreve.bash)

[get_official_devices.py](https://github.com/Evolution-X/vendor_evolution/blob/udc/tools/get_official_devices.py)

Going to the link listed in the last script, I can view the .jason file. This is looking like it might be an internet or server issue.

Going to try and reset my router.

Comment: You could also run `set -x` to turn on debug tracing, so you can see what's happening as envsetup.sh runs and what step is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
set -x
```

allowed me to see exactly what was hanging up when accessing a file via url. Resetting my router fixed it. thanks @gordon davisson